# How to use R for basic image processing

Tags: r, image-processing

I am currently working on an application of Principal Component Analysis to visual data in R.

In Matlab, one can invoke commands such as "im2double" and "mat2gray" to convert a bitmap into a numerical matrix and back again to an image.

I was wondering whether this can be achieved in R, maybe via additional packages.

Comment: Off topic I think as not a statistical question.   Probably better for R-help than here. But there are packages like bmp, readbitmap, pixmap, and raster which may do what you want - depending on exactly what that is (I don't quite see the link to principal components).

Comment: The `image` command will allow you to display simple greyscale or indexed images, e.g. `image(1:100,1:100,(1:100)%*%t(1:100)/100, col=rgb(1:100/100,1:100/100,1:100/100))`, but the EBImage package that @MattBagg talks about below seems far superior.  As far as I know, base R has no support for loading images, so you'd have to preprocess with netpbm or similar.

Comment: There are two packages available for image processing: EBImage and adimpro.

Answer (score 7):

I've used the EBImage package ([vignette](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.pdf) here) available on bioconductor to work with and manipulate images:

```
# installing package if needed
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("EBImage")

library(EBImage) 
f = readImage(system.file("images", "lena-color.png", package="EBImage"))
str(f)
#Formal class 'Image' [package "EBImage"] with 2 slots
#  ..@ .Data    : num [1:512, 1:512, 1:3] 0.886 0.886 0.875 0.875 0.886 ...
#  ..@ colormode: int 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I was curious enough to try this out; clearly a package is a better solution, but if you really want to stick to base R, this will load a png (albeit upside down and backwards; that's probably fixable).  It assumes the presence of the netpbm tools, so probably won't work out of the box on Windows systems.

```
readPng <- function(pngFile) {
  contents <- system(paste('pngtopnm',pngFile,'| pnmtoplainpnm'),intern=TRUE)
  imgDims <- strsplit(contents[2], ' ')
  width <- as.numeric(imgDims[[1]][1])
  height <- as.numeric(imgDims[[1]][2])
  rawimg <- scan(textConnection(contents),skip=3)
  return(list(
    x=1:width,
    y=1:height,
    z=matrix(rawimg,width),
    width=width,
    height=height))
}
```

You can run `image(img)` on the list returned from this function directly, or access the per-pixel values using img$z.

Answer (score 2):

Two methods to install the package.

1. install through command line if you have no Editor like RStudio
2. install the command line by entering into R interpreter using R command in bash.

Go to prompt where you can execute R commands.  here these the basic image processing command.

execute this command to install the Bio conductor backage biocLite, which will help to install the EBIMage package( This package is used widely for image processing)

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
```

install the EMImage package to use image processing commands.

```
biocLite("EBImage")
```

Load the EBIMage package to use the image processing

```
library("EBImage")
# Reading image from computer
img=readImage(files="~/Desktop/Prog/R/tinago.JPG")
display(img)
img1=img+ 0.2 # increase brightness
img2=img- 0.2 # decrease brightness
display(img1) # Display images in browser or graphical window
display(img2) # Display images in browser or graphical window
img3= img * 0.5 # decrease contrast 
img4=img * 2    # increase contrast
display(img3); display(img4)  # show result images
img5=img^2 # increase Gamma correction
img6=img^0.7 # decrease Gamma correction
display(img5); display(img6)  # Display result images
```

Note : readImage to read the image. Display is used to view the image in Graphical Window.

Answer (score 1):

The relatively new package `tiff`  will read and write TIF images quite nicely.
All the same,  for anything other than relatively simple image manipulation, I'd recommend using ImageJ or SAOImage9 from the Harvard-Smithsonian group:  http://www.cfa.harvard.edu/resources/software.html .

I've written tools in R to do pixel merging, pixel splitting, Sobel & Hough transforms, decolorization, etc., with great success.  Ultimately the choice of application depends on the size of your images and the type of processing you need to do.

Comment: Why not share some of your tools?

Comment: @by0  sadly, there's a big difference between some quick hacks that get the job done and a function which is robust, does proper input validation, and in particular for image processing, is reasonably fast.  None of my image tools meet such qualifications.